# SQL Query counting entries in 3 Tables

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL Database with 3 tables:

**table1: user**

```
id | nickname
1    peter
2    tom
```

**table2: posts**

```
user_id | title | text
1         hmmm    bla
1         yeah    blub
2         blub    dada
1         yuhu    asdf
```

**table3: messages**

```
user_id | title | message
1         hello   bla
2         hi      blub
2         hey     dada
2         huhu    asdf
```

How do I count every entry from posts/messages for each user in one query?

Comment: Knowing the database would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       COALESCE(b.cnt_b, 0) posts_count, 
       COALESCE(c.cnt_c, 0) messages_count
  FROM user a LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) cnt_b
                    FROM posts b 
                 GROUP BY user_id
            ) b
     ON a.user_id = b.user_id LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) cnt_c
                    FROM messages c 
                 GROUP BY user_id
            ) c
    ON a.user_id = c.user_id
```